# find a distribution if given range and probability

Tags: probability

I am a loss to understand this probability question:

> 1. For a variable Z-distribution:
>
> $$\mathsf P(Z < Z_0) = 0.8272$$
>
> Find $z_0$. A diagram is needed.

(the sub 0 means it's the variable z and the a small 0 below it. [edit: with MathJax notation this is done by an underscore.] )

any hints to get me on the right track or what to search for?

I apologize for not giving correct context. This was the entire question as it was given to me.

Comment: You've written gibberish. Please clean it up and be very accurate, or no one can help you.

Comment: Well, a **Z-distribution** is a (standardised) probability distribution with mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $1$.  The type of distribution is *usually* a normal distribution; called the standard normal distribution.  Probability questions using Z-distributions typically involve expressions of the form $\mathsf P(a\leq Z\leq b)$ or $\mathsf P(Z\leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2})$ or such.  Nothing else in the OP makes any sense at all, and the question is totally lacking in context.

Comment: i apologize, i tried to add more information above

Answer (score 0):

Is this meant to be a **standard normal distribution**?  This is the most typical Z-distribution, but not exclusively so.

You should have access to a "Z-Table", or "Standard Normal" table as part of your course materials; either included in the course's text book, or inside a separate booklet of tables.  Otherwise you can look up an ever so handy [online calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx) and find that:

$$\mathsf P(Z\leqslant 0.943)=0.8272$$

Drawing a diagram of where this happens on a standard normal distribution is a task left to you.  Just draw a bell curve showing the mean at $z=0$, the standard deviation at $z=\pm 1$ and thus demonstrate how everything to the left of the line at $z_0=0.943$ covers $82.72\%$ of the area under the curve.